# Error implementing PayPal payment in PHP website

Tags: php, paypal

I'm struggling trying to ollow PayPal paiyment on my PHP website. I built wrote the following method to hadle order creation, but I keep getting an error when trying to parse PayPal response to JSON.

```
        function createOrder($amount, $info) {
            $pp_env = PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT_MODE == 1 ? PAYPAL_SANDBOX_ENV : PAYPAL_LIVE_ENV ;
            $accessToken = $this->generateAccessToken();
            $url = $pp_env."/v2/checkout/orders";
            $data = array(
                'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
                'purchase_units' => array(
                    array(
                        'amount' => array(
                            'currency_code' => CURRENCY_CODE,
                            'value' => $amount,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            );
            $headers = array(
                "Content-type: application/json",
                "Accept: application/json",
                "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken,
            );
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return json_decode($response, true);
        }
```

My error is client-side when I try to convert HTTP response to JSON using this code:

```
        createOrder() {
          return fetch("<?=base_url("public/paypal_create")?>", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((order) => order.id);
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqJSi.png)

Following is the response I can see using browser dev tools:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FToTp.png)

Anyone can figure out whqt I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing there's some JavaScript that is automatically being appended to your output? You need to disable `debugbar_loader` or whatever that is on that script. Edit: Perhaps you need `define('CI_DEBUG', 0);` (I am not familiar with CI)

Comment: Also, its best to include your response as text in the case, images are problematic.

Comment: Incredible, it's working now after turning CI_DEBUG to false. Thanks so much!

Comment: Neat, I'll add it as an answer for you to accept as your solution

Answer (score 0):

As you are using CodeIgniter, you may need to suppress your debug/developer information. This seems to be impacting the data that your JavaScript is expecting.

On the script that is rendering your JSON add the following code.

```
define('CI_DEBUG', 0);
```

https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/testing/debugging.html#enabling-the-toolbar

Answer (score -1):

Use the Network tab to see what your server is responding from its create-order and capture-order routes when your buttons are clicked. The response must be only a valid JSON object that the frontend button code JS can parse.

Based on the error information in your question, it appears the response contains additional HTML things (not just the JSON) including a debug_loader, which is invalid for a fetch/XHR trying to parse that response as JSON.

Comment: Yes that's it. As I'm using CodeIgniter 4 I turned CI_DEBUG to false and it's working now. Thanks for your help!